# What if use apply class property instead of newInstance()?

Tags: android, kotlin

We use this factory method pattern for re-instatiate fragment to protect data in constructor.. and then,, I thought... what if I use empty constructor and apply property??

What is difference between these two method?

1. normal method

```
class A(){
    private val str = ""

    override onCreate(~~~){
         str = argument.getString("key")
    }

    companion object{
      fun newInstance(){
        return A().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString("key", str)
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

2. method I am wondering

```
class A(){
    val str = ""
}

other class{
    A().apply{
        str = "I am A"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply` doesn't solve anything. Is just a shortcut for "fixing" the instance of a class you're working with.

It's exactly the same as if you were to do:

```
val a = A()
a.str = "I am A"
```

No difference.

---

The thing about `Fragments` is that you must be using `arguments` to pass data to them. This is because `Fragments` can be re-created by the `FragmentManager` and field values (`str` field in your example) will be lost, but `arguments` `Bundle` will be retained.

You can do that however you want. Factory functions - `newInstance` - are just a well known simple pattern that tries to force using `arguments`.

Comment: I understand..! and then, how can I pass the lambda data(ex. Event function)? Can I pass lambda data by using arguments?

Comment: There's no simple answer to this question @이상은. The lambda in itself is `Serializable` but this is a case-by-case thing. Do a google search for "Lambda in bundle" for some hints. I would suggest passing a lambda `identifier` (any type of `id`, e.g. a `String`), and resolving the lambda in the fragment based on this `id`.